# using only power series to show $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

What is the simplest way to show  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
using only power series but not Fourier series?

Comment: Do any of the methods mentioned at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2 answer your question? It is not clear to me what "using only power series" means.

Comment: Different proofs can be found here(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2) and here(http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to search for questions with math formulas.